# Passing django settings to django template using angularjs

Tags: python, django, angularjs, django-templates, django-views

I have this `settings.py` that include my `global_constants.py`

Now I want to access the Constants that I have defined in my `global_constants.py` in my Django Template using Angular JS. How to do that?

My `global_constants.py` contaains the following function:

```
def my_image_urls(request):
    return {
        "URL_ONE": "http://mywebsite.com/IMAGE/Image_one",
        "URL_TWO": "http://mywebsite.com/IMAGE/Image_two",
    }
```

Now I want  to Access this `URL_ONE` and `URL_TWO` in my `template/index.html` which is called by my `Views.py`. But MY PURPOSE IS TO CALL THIS USING **ANGULARJS** into my template. How exactly I can achieve that. Need an overview so that I get on right direction :)

How I want to use it in my Templete is like this:

```
{{ URL_ONE }} /myimage.jpeg
{{ URL_TWO }} /myimage_two.jpeg
```

**PLEASE NOTE THAT I AM USING ANGULARJS FOR MY TEMPLATE**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting values from django into angularjs there are two main ways:

- Create a view that returns JSON
- In the view that serves your angularjs application, use django templates to encode extra information either into a script tag or data attributes.

So if you absolutely do not want to use any django templating then your angular js app will need to call your JSON settings view.

If you wish to eliminate that initial round trip then use django templating to inject your values into javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var DJANGO_URLS = {URL_ONE: "{{URL_ONE}}", URL_TWO: "{{URL_TWO}}"};
</script>
```

Your angular app can now access the variables globally (ie window.DJANGO_URLS).